# Contractions and finding Fixed Points

Tags: real-analysis

Define a map D on $C[0,1]$ by:

$$D(f(x)) = \begin{cases}
  \frac 23 + \frac 13 f(3x), & \text{if }1 \le x \le \frac 13 , \\
  (2+f(1)) (\frac 23 - x), & \text{if }\frac 13 \le x \le \frac 23, \\
x - \frac 23, & \text {if } \frac 23 \le x \le 1
\end{cases}$$

Show that $D$ is a contraction and determine the fixed point for D

My attempt:

$$|T(f(x)−Tg(x)|=|(\frac 23 + \frac 13 f(3x)− \frac 23+ \frac 13 g(3x)|= \frac 13 |f(3x)−g(3x)| ≤ \frac 13|f−g|_\infty$$

Then, $||Tf−Tg||∞≤ \frac 13||f−g||$

$$|Tf(x)−Tg(x)|=|(2+f(1))(\frac 23−x)−(2+g(1))(\frac 23−x)|=|(\frac 23−x)−(f(1)−g(1)|=|\frac {(2−3x)}3||f(1)−g(1)≤ \frac 13||f−g|_\infty$$

But I got stuck with the last one, here is my attempt for that

$$|Tf(x)−Tg(x)|=|x− \frac 23−(x− \frac 23)|=|2x|$$

I don't know how to show the above equation is a contraction, and determine the fixed point for $D$.

**EDIT** $$|Tf(x)−Tg(x)|=|x− \frac 23−(x− \frac 23)|= 0 $$

Comment: Please clean up the fractions in your post; it's very difficult to understand right now. Assuming that your post accurately defines $D(f)$ on the last third of $[0,1]$, then $D(f)$ and $D(g)$ are in fact equal on that interval, and so their difference on $[2/3,1]$ will not contribute anything towards the sup norm $||D(f)-D(g)||_\infty$.

Comment: @Jonas Sorry about the messed up fractions. Could you please have a look at now?

Comment: you gave $\frac 23 + \frac 13 f(3x),  \text{if }1 \le x \le \frac 13$ , it's  $0\le x \le \frac 13$. Or ? ?

Comment: Well, it looks like my first comment has the gist of it. Just note that on $[2/3,1]$, $Df$ and $Dg$ are equal, hence $|Df(x)-Dg(x)| = 0$, which finishes the proof that $D$ is a contraction. You have a sign error in your last equation, hence the confusion.

Comment: @Jonas Then my last equation is not contraction? Or $|Df(x) - Dg(x)|= 0 \le \frac 13 |x-y|$ ? How do I determine the fixed point?

Comment: By definition, a fixed point $f$ of the contraction satisfies $D(f) = f$. Apply the definition of $D$ to figure out what $f$ must be. For example, since $Df(x) = x - 2/3$ on $[2/3,1]$, we must have that $f(x) = x - 2/3$ on the same interval also.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas ! But I am still stuck with that could you explain more about what you did in your example? or Please provide me some links or the like where I could check about that property $D(f) = f$.

Comment: Feel free to read more about fixed points [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_%28mathematics%29). I am sensing some confusion here about the fixed point; note that $D$ is an operator defined on the function space $C[0,1]$, not on the interval $[0,1]$. Therefore it acts on functions $f$, and so its fixed point is a function, not a point in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas! I will figure that out!

Comment: @Jonas, I saw a hint in the textbook that says that "repeatedly apply $D$ to the function $f(x) = \frac 13$. Given your hints, I need to set $D(f) = f$, so I will have all the equations equal to $\frac 13$ then I got fixed for the $Df(x)$

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you've successfully shown that your transformation is a contraction. To find the fixed function, we can simply iterate the iteration a few times to see that the graph will look something like so:

[image]

Thus, your answer should be defined piecewise with different definitions on the intervals of the form 
$$\frac{1}{3^n} \leq x \leq \frac{2}{3^n} \: \: \text{ and } \: \:
  \frac{2}{3^{n+1}} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{3^n}.$$
It's pretty easy to see that this function is fixed by your transformation.  The last part of your transformation (over the interval $2/3\leq x \leq 1$) implies that $T(f)(x)=x-2/3$ for *any* function at all and the second part (over the interval $1/3\leq x \leq 2/3$) implies that $T(f)(x) = 7(2 - 3 x)/9$ for any function satisfying $f(1)=1/3$. The graph above certainly satisfies both of these. The first portion of your transformation implies that the graph of $f$ over the interval $0\leq x \leq 1/3$ should be a scaled copy of the entire graph by the factor $1/3$.  Again, the graph above appears to satisfy this:

[image]

Finally, note that application of this self-similarity to the piecewise definition of the fixed function over the intervals $1/3 \leq x \leq 2/3$ and $2/3 \leq x \leq 1$ should yield the definition of the fixed function over the general intervals of the form
$$\frac{1}{3^n} \leq x \leq \frac{2}{3^n} \: \: \text{ and } \: \:
  \frac{2}{3^{n+1}} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{3^n}.$$